# Iam trying to create an react app using (create-react-app app-name) , but its showing error could anybody tell me why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-redux, node-modules

I have tried clearing cache but its not solving my problem. Its working until few hours back . after that i have used `npm run eject` on one of my other project . After that iam getting this error. I will attach a error file along with log .Can anyone help me with this?

**Error**

```
Creating a new React app in F:\React Learning\meals\meal-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pcmaster\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-06T14_53_15_643Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting meal-app/ from F:\React Learning\meals
Done.

F:\React Learning\meals>
```

**Generated Logfile**

```
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   '--save-exact',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   'react',
1 verbose cli   'react-dom',
1 verbose cli   'react-scripts',
1 verbose cli   'cra-template' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose npm-session bb041aca5c7d9fbf
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-dom@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-scripts@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for cra-template@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
11 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 3ms
12 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 363ms
13 verbose type system
14 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
14 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
14 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
14 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
14 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
14 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
14 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
14 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
15 verbose cwd F:\React Learning\meals\meal-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ENOTFOUND
21 error errno ENOTFOUND
22 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
23 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
23 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
23 error network
23 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
23 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Iam New to react. i have created a react many react app using the same command . But dont know why its not working this time. I have a updated nodejs.

Comment: What do you get when trying to open "https://registry.npmjs.org/react" on your web browser?

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: What steps did you follow to create new react project? You should not have `create-react-app` globally installed. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538 for steps.

Comment: @Jackyef  It will return some json data.

Comment: @NageshDhope I have  tried both the ways but result is same....

Comment: @AjeetShah Thank you so much. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

step 1 ) Clearing Cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

step 2) Run Command :

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

for npm 5.2+ or higher.

The exact reason for the Error is unknown. But these 2 steps worked for me.